# How can I assert on a Java Hashmap of Arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, junit, hashmap, multidimensional-array

I'm building a new hashmap ( < String , String[] > ) by combining three other hashmaps ( < String , String > ) and adding the filename.  How do I assert the new hashmap is correct?  The nested array is making the test fail.

This code is a simplified example of my failing test:

```
@Test
public void injectArrayIntoHashMap() {
  HashMap map = new HashMap();
  map.put("hi", new String[] { "hello", "howdy" });

  HashMap newMap = new HashMap();
  newMap.put("hi", new String[] { "hello", "howdy" });

  assertEquals(map, newMap);
}
```

**UPDATE:**  Okay, based on Hna's advice, I got the test working with an ArrayList.  However, I then realized I needed to instantiate an object inside of the ArrayList and now the test is failing.  It seems to have to do with the fact that the objects inside the ArrayList have different memory addresses.  I'm new to Java and inserting the object in the ArrayList this was my attempt to avoid an "if" statement.  Is there a better way?  Or just an easy answer to making my test pass?

Here is the new code:

```
@Test
public void sampleTest() throws IOException {
  HashMap expectedResult = new HashMap();
  expectedResult.put("/images",                   new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("/images", new Public())));
  expectedResult.put("/stylesheets",              new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("/stylesheets", new Public())));

  HashMap actualResult = test();

  assertEquals(expectedResult, actualResult);
}

public HashMap test() {
  HashMap hashMap = new HashMap();
  hashMap.put("/images",      new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("/images",      new Public())));
  hashMap.put("/stylesheets", new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("/stylesheets", new Public())));
  return hashMap;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This fails because when the `assertEquals` does the comparison between the arrays it is checking if the memory addresses are equal which obviously fails. One way to solve your problem is to use a container like ArrayList which implements the `equals` method and can be compared in the way you want.

Here's an example:

```
public void injectArrayIntoHashMap() {
      HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> map = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
      ArrayList<String> l1 = new ArrayList<String>();
      l1.add("hello");
      l1.add("howdy");
      map.put("hi", l1);

      HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> newMap = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
      ArrayList<String> l2 = new ArrayList<String>();
      l2.add("hello");
      l2.add("howdy");
      newMap.put("hi", l2);

      System.out.println(map.equals(newMap));
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  Worked perfectly.  I always shy away from ArrayLists (I'm new to Java).  Guess I should start using them more.  Oh and thanks for the code.  That was helpful as I was confused how to build the ArrayLists and insert data.

Comment: Hi, Hna.  This was working and then I ran into a problem.  Instead of inserting an arraylist of Strings, I now insert an arraylist of a string and object (an instantiated class).  And it's failing.  :o(  Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post an example? What is the the type of the key? What is the type of the value?

Comment: Thank you so much, Hna!  I posted an update in the original thread.